# How can I pass the fixed params data to existing form using link_to instead of submitting form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Now I have a form view like this

```
<%=form_for(([@community, @comment]), :remote => true, :class => 'form' ) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :body, :id => "body", :class => "chat" %> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn">submit</button>
<% end %>

<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    Request to <%= request(@community, comment.user) %> <br />
<% end %>
```

Then **rake routes** shows this

```
POST   /communities/:community_id/comments(.:format)     comments#create
```

**application_helper** is coded like this. I have no idea what to put within `create_community_comment_path(????????)` neither its correct path.

```
def request(community, user)
    if user
        nickname = user.profile.try(:nickname) 
        body = "You've got a request from " + nickname
        link_to "<span class='btn'>request</span>".html_safe , create_community_comment_path(community, body),{:method => :post}
    end
end
```

Can anyone show me how to make `link_to` to pass fixed params to the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

`link_to "<span class='btn'>request</span>".html_safe , create_community_comment_path(community, body, :parm1=>"Valu1", :parm2=>"Valu2"),{:method => :post}`

Comment: Thanks. but first of all. I made up that path `create_community_comment_path` Will it work??

Comment: If you are using nested route then it should be `community_comment_path` else `comment_path`. Have a look on [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: thanks! I made that way. but now it show the link to `example.com/communities/california/comments.You've  got a request from John` if I click this, it gets error:( `You've got...` part shouldn't be params? I have no idea:

Comment: Remove the "body" from `community_comment_path(community, body, :parm1=>"Valu1", :parm2=>"Valu2")` and add it in <span>